# Korean food that was wrapped in tin foil

Tags: nuts, mushrooms, korean-cuisine

I have a fond memory of a dish from awhile back however I do not know where I ate it at nor what it was. All I know is it was some Korean BBQ place near San Jose or Cupertino CA the kind where there is a large cooking surface in the bulk of the table and you cook everything yourself.

The most memorable thing served came out wrapped in tin foil and was placed on the cooking surface for some time. What came out was absolutely incredible although I don’t remember what it was. From what I can remember there were mushrooms, nuts and some sort of amazing juice/oil. It had incredible umami and slightly woody taste to it.

I have never seen this dish at any other Korean bbq place, does anyone the name of this dish?

Comment: Recipe requests are off-topic, so asking what dishes combine certain ingredients will almost certainly be closed. Asking what the dish you got was is on topic, I've edited your question accordingly, I hope that's okay with you. If someone can identify it you can search for a recipe.

Comment: I know there are a lot of Korean places in California, but if you went with someone, they might give you some clues to help you track down the restaurant, and from there, you can look up their menu.  (unless it's seasonal, and then you might have to contact them)

Comment: There's a chance you might be able to pinpoint the restaurant you ate at by retracing your route (from that day) on Google Maps .... (just an idea)

Comment: This https://www.saveur.com/salmon-scallion-mushroom-foil-yaki-recipe ?